# Add CSS dynamically when hover on button

Tags: html, css

http://exrx.net/concrete5/store/low-volume-progressive-intensity-weight-training
http://exrx.net/concrete5/store/low-volume-progressive-intensity-weight-training-1

Here are my website link. I have `translate this` button on pages. When I hover on `translate this` button, the language section is shown 50 pixels below.

How can I add css dynamically that add top position to language section. Right now I am using below css

```
.ttb-panel { top: 235px !important; }
```

This only works when one `div` with class `.ccm-custom-style-adstop` (Advertise after page title ) is not there.

I have given both page link.
What CSS rule will work[image]?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("# TRANSLATE BUTTON ID").mouseover(function(){
    $("# TRANSLATE DIV ID").addClass("ttb-panel");
});
```

Comment: There will be different top position of translate DIV section. Can you check the two links I have provided, Please ?